# ¿Cómo guardar cambios del json en la misma columna o en una nueva?

Tags: python, json, bucle-for, diccionarios, jupyter

Quiero saber qué puedo agregarle al código para que me guarde en la misma columna o en una nueva los json pero con los cambios que estoy realizando mediante los condicionales (algo como sobreescribirlo con los cambios incluidos). No soy tan diestro en python pero estoy aprendiendo, si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

```
for i in xs2['input_parameters2']:
datos = json.loads(i)
#new = []
#print(datos['minuta_id'])
for companias in datos['companies']:
        if 'financial_accounts' in 'companies':
            for dict1 in range(len(xs2)):
                if companias['ruc'] == xs2.loc[dict,'RUC']:
                    #companias['financial_accounts'].update(xs2.loc[dict,'dic'])
                    companias['financial_accounts'] =[
                        {"code":371,"name":"Inversiones en valores","value":xs2.loc[dict,'INVERSIONES_EN_VALORES']},
                        {"code":408,"name":"Capital","value":xs2.loc[dict,'CAPITAL_FIJO']},
                        {"code":414,"name":"Resultados acumulados","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_ACUMULADOS']},
                        {"code":415,"name":"Resultado del ejercicio","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_DEL_EJERCICIO']},
                        {"code":416,"name":"Ventas","value":xs2.loc[dict,'VENTAS_NETAS']}]
                    print(companias['financial_accounts'])
                    print(companias['ruc'])      
                    
        else:
            for dict in range(len(xs2)):
                if companias['ruc'] == xs2.loc[dict,'RUC']:
                    companias['financial_accounts'] =[
                        {"code":371,"name":"Inversiones en valores","value":xs2.loc[dict,'INVERSIONES_EN_VALORES']},
                        {"code":408,"name":"Capital","value":xs2.loc[dict,'CAPITAL_FIJO']},
                        {"code":414,"name":"Resultados acumulados","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_ACUMULADOS']},
                        {"code":415,"name":"Resultado del ejercicio","value":xs2.loc[dict,'RESULTADOS_DEL_EJERCICIO']},
                        {"code":416,"name":"Ventas","value":xs2.loc[dict,'VENTAS_NETAS']}]
                    #print(new)
```

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: Amigo ya lo coloqué como texto